# Update / Upgrade SharePoint 2013 App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, upgrade

I have an SharePoint provider hosted app. In my developement eniorement I added some new Columns to a list. After a deploy I added a new list to the SharePoint App.

I consider that after I deploy the app from Visual Studio (hit F5) that the already existing lists are empty. 
This happens only if the app is modified (like adding a list or s.th.).

How can I prevent this? because when I add a new feature to my app. I think the customers won't be happy if their data is lost after an update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow an upgrade process for the app.

> For an update, you use the same product ID in the app manifest that
>   you used for the original version. The version number in the app
>   manifest should be greater than the version number of the original app
>   or the most recent update.

See more at:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179904(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179904%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/06/13/upgrading-your-app-for-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Hi, i tried it with the same productid and a higher Version ist the manifest. But i got there also an empty list, and i am wondering why i Must increase the verion to prevent from whiping my listdata.

Comment: @Sascha, did you try using UpgradedEventEndpoint web service to preserve the data.http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/549fe831-4113-480e-ad78-0e9d8d8c7d09/how-to-upgrade-apps-without-loosing-data

Comment: @Sascha, I just included some part of the answer, you will need to follow the whole article